# Titanium Studio - Can't start Android App in Emulator

Tags: android, macos, titanium, android-2.2-froyo

I have built an application with Titanium Studio. The IOS Simulator works perfectly.
But I can't build my app in the Android emulator. I have the Android SDK v.22 and I am using Titanium 3.1.3.

Could someone tell me what I must do?

I get this log:

```
[INFO] Titanium SDK version: 3.1.3 (09/18/13 12:00 222f4d1)

[INFO] Waiting for the Android Emulator to become available

[ERROR] Timed out waiting for android.process.acore

[INFO] Fastdev server running, deploying in Fastdev mode

[INFO] Copying CommonJS modules...

[INFO] Copying project resources..

[ERROR] Exception occured while building Android project:

[ERROR] Traceback (most recent call last):

[ERROR]   File "/Users/timstrakerjahn/Library/Application
Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.3.GA/android/builder.py", line 2598, in <module>

[ERROR]     builder.build_and_run(False, avd_id, debugger_host=debugger_host, profiler_host=profiler_host)

[ERROR]   File "/Users/timstrakerjahn/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.3.GA/android/builder.py", line 2245, in build_and_run

[ERROR]     self.copy_project_resources()

[ERROR]   File "/Users/timstrakerjahn/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.3.GA/android/builder.py", line 865, in copy_project_resources

[ERROR]     self.project_deltas = self.project_deltafy.scan()

[ERROR]   File "/Users/timstrakerjahn/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.3.GA/android/deltafy.py", line 163, in scan

[ERROR]     self.scan_path(self.dir, deltas)

[ERROR]   File "/Users/timstrakerjahn/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.3.GA/android/deltafy.py", line 195, in scan_path

[ERROR]     self.scan_path(absolute_path, deltas)

[ERROR]   File "/Users/timstrakerjahn/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.3.GA/android/deltafy.py", line 203, in scan_path

[ERROR]     file_delta = self.check_delta(absolute_path, path_stat)

[ERROR]   File "/Users/timstrakerjahn/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.3.GA/android/deltafy.py", line 147, in check_delta

[ERROR]     timestamp = self.get_timestamp(path)

[ERROR]   File "/Users/timstrakerjahn/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.3.GA/android/deltafy.py", line 116, in get_timestamp

[ERROR]     c.execute('select modified from timestamps where path = ?', (path,))

[ERROR] ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.

[ERROR] :  Build process exited with code 1

[ERROR] :  Project failed to build after 46s 605ms

[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can occur if you

- have file names with non-standard characters (like ñ or é).
  Switch to standard unicode characters in your file names only.
- have incidentally added a PSD file to your assets

This is the link to the original question at the appcelerator developer forum:
http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/139685/programmingerror-you-must-not-use-8-bit-bytestrings-unless-you-use-a-textfactory-that-can-interpret-8-bit-bytestrings